# Каково устройство файлового менеджера?

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать простой файловый менеджер для Windows на c#, подскажите с чего начать и есть ли какая-нибудь литература, где этот вопрос разбирается. Смотрела книгу Робинсона второй том, но там все как-то сложновато, так что прошу помощи тут

Comment: Перестаньте искать и начните делать! А уже потом задавайте конкретный вопрос. Для решения такой задачи хватит базовых навыков программирования...

Comment: https://youtu.be/6OwyNiLPDNw?list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M&t=270